# Haskell/GHC Generics documentation example missing a typeclass constraint?

Tags: haskell, generics, ghc

I'm following the tutorial for building a Generic "encode" function for datatypes from the [hackage documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/GHC-Generics.html) for `GHC.Generics`. I've copy-pasted the code up to (and including) the section "The wrapper and generic default", but I get the following error:

```
Main.hs:35:14:
    Could not deduce (Encode' (Rep a)) arising from a use of ‘encode'’
    from the context (Encode a)
      bound by the class declaration for ‘Encode’
      at Main.hs:(32,1)-(35,29)
    or from (Generic a)
      bound by the type signature for encode :: Generic a => a -> [Bool]
      at Main.hs:33:13-23
    In the expression: encode' (from x)
    In an equation for ‘encode’: encode x = encode' (from x)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

The code I've copied is as follows:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts  #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveAnyClass    #-}
module Main where

import GHC.Generics

class Encode' f where
  encode' :: f p -> [Bool]

instance Encode' V1 where
  encode' x = undefined

instance Encode' U1 where
  encode' U1 = []

instance (Encode' f, Encode' g) => Encode' (f :+: g) where
  encode' (L1 x) = False : encode' x
  encode' (R1 x) = True  : encode' x

instance (Encode' f, Encode' g) => Encode' (f :*: g) where
  encode' (x :*: y) = encode' x ++ encode' y

instance (Encode c) => Encode' (K1 i c) where
  encode' (K1 x) = encode x

instance (Encode' f) => Encode' (M1 i t f) where
  encode' (M1 x) = encode' x

class Encode a where
  encode :: a -> [Bool]
  default encode :: (Generic a) => a -> [Bool]
  encode x = encode' (from x)
```

I think the problem is at the final class declaration (`class Encode a where ...`). I've fixed it by adding an extra constraint, to get this:

```hs
class Encode a where
  encode :: a -> [Bool]                                                                                                                                                              
  default encode :: (Generic a, Encode' (Rep a)) => a -> [Bool]
  encode x = encode' (from x)
```

This seems to work as advertised - I can declare new datatypes and make them encodable with `DeriveAnyClass` and `deriving`. However, I'm not really sure why my fix is necessary. My question is:

- Are the docs wrong?
- Should the `Encode' (Rep a)` constraint be present in the example code on hackage?
- If not, what should I add to make the code work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, I think the docs are wrong. The constraint is required.

Comment: Cool! Who do I talk to / where do I go to fix them?

Comment: @statusfailed Actually, it's already fixed: http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/master/libraries/html/base/GHC-Generics.html#g:13 (thanks to Ben Gamari).